# Arraylist only retrieves the last value

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

Hi I am passing an arraylist from one activity to another using Parcelable..

Now the problem is that when I click on BILL, all the rows are populated with the last value of the arraylist..So I guess I am not able to retreive the whole arraylist in the calling activity...

Here is the relevant code..

SpinPizza.java

```
public class SpinPizza extends Activity{
store temp= new store();

     int i=0;

ArrayList<store> B = new ArrayList<store>();


//oncreate method



  int n=Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());

     temp.setOrder(s.getSelectedItem().toString(), s1.getSelectedItem().toString(),n);

          B.add(temp);

             TextView objText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pl);

              TextView objText1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pl2);

              objText.setText(B.get(i).getPizzaName());

             objText1.setText(temp.getPizzaSize());

                 i++;




    });

      Button next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bill);    

      next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View view) {

              Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Bill.class);

                  myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myclass",B);

              startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

          }

      });

}
```

Bill.java

```
public class Bill extends Activity {
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

this.setContentView(R.layout.calc);
ArrayList<store> B1 = new ArrayList<store>();

store temp1=new store();

Bundle bj=getIntent().getExtras();


    B1=bj.getParcelableArrayList("myclass");

  TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);



                      for(int i=0;i<B1.size();i++)
        { 
             TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
             tr.setId(100+i);
            temp1=B1.get(i);         
             tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



            TextView b = new TextView(this);
        b.setText(temp1.getPizzaName()); 
        b.setId(200+i);

        TextView b1 = new TextView(this);
        b1.setText(temp1.getPizzaSize());
        b1.setId(300+i);

       TextView b2 = new TextView(this);
       b2.setText(String.valueOf(temp1.getQuantity()));
       b2.setId(400+i);


        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(b);

        b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(b1);



        b2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tr.addView(b2);



tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


 }}
```

}

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the creation of `temp`, nor i can see the iteration using in your `temp` modifier line `temp.setOrder(s.getSelectedItem().toString(), s1.getSelectedItem().toString(),n);`. It seems that you don't use `i` there that's why you have equal records.

Comment: @user639183 I do it all...temp is created in the 2nd line..(See the code)...Actually i dint post the whole code...My bad...Here is the iteration...

Comment: public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&  (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) { int n=Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());

            temp.setOrder(s.getSelectedItem().toString(), s1.getSelectedItem().toString(),n );
 B.add(temp);
 
           //text view display

               i++;